# What are the privacy implications of apps that use Android System WebView?

Tags: browser, privacy, webview, html5, cookies

From what I've researched, Android System WebView supports cookies and HTML5 local storage.

When do those cookies and local storage items get cleared?

For example, Samsung Messenger (Samsung's default SMS app) uses WebView to load web links (even in Android Nougat).  If the loaded web page generates cookies and HTML5 local storage items, will those items be available:

1. to every web page loaded within Samsung Messenger during that session?
2. to every web page loaded within Samsung Messenger during later Messenger sessions?
3. to other apps that use WebView?

Comment: Looks like not even a bounty provokes an answer here. What a pity. Does really nobody know?

Comment: @Izzy Wow... besides you and me, currently only 66 views, even with a bounty.

Comment: Nobody interested in privacy (or in Webview) it seems. Sad. Great question btw, I'd loved to have the answer! Was hoping for Dan here to be honest :) And yes, sad not even the bounty was able to draw more attention…